# Intern test case execution hangs forever after importing snapsvg-cjs in ts file

Tags: javascript, dojo, snap.svg, intern

After importing `snapsvg-cjs` in .ts file(in Dojo2 Project) intern test case got stuck after executing all test cases.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Isn't the import syntax like `import * as Snap from "snapsvg-cjs";` or `import {Snap} from "snapsvg-cjs";`?

Comment: Are you saying that importing snapsvg in a test file causes Intern to hang when finished, but importing snapsvg in your application code does not? Could you post the actual import statements used in each case?

Comment: I am working on Dojo 2 project that is in typescript so imported snap.sbj-cjs as follows:-
import "snapsvg-cjs";
// declaring types for snapsvg
declare const Snap: ISnapSvg;

As snapsvg-cjs does not have types defined, I handle it as above.
@jason0x43

Comment: Below import does't working 
import * as Snap from "snapsvg-cjs"; or import {Snap} from "snapsvg-cjs"; Throwing error like - 
Could not find a declaration file for module 'snapsvg-cjs'. '/Users/synerzip/c8-canvas/node_modules/snapsvg-cjs/dist/snap.svg-cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
@barbsan

Comment: The types for snapsvg are available in the `@types/snapsvg` package.

Comment: @types/snapsvg-cjs is not available for "snapsvg-cjs" @jason0x43

Comment: Hmmm...tricky. It's the same package as snapsvg, so the types are presumably the same, but the naming difference is annoying. I guess you're not using @dojo/loader?

Answer (score 0):

When Intern is stuck open after test cases have finished, it typically means that a file or socket is still open. Intern is done, but the Node process won't shut down while handles are still open. This can happen if, say, an asynchronous process were started in a test without returning a Promise.

One way to diagnose what's preventing the Intern process from exiting is to run it with [wtfnode](https://github.com/myndzi/wtfnode). When wtfnode is used to run a node program and the program is manually killed (like with with ctrl-c), wftnode will display any open resources. Run Intern with `wtfnode`, ctrl-c when it appears to be hung, then see what's still open.